# color seaborn swarmplot points with additional metadata beyond hue in boxplot

Tags: python, seaborn, visualization, boxplot, swarmplot

Say I have data that I want to box plot and overlay with a swarm plot in seaborn, whose colors of the points add additional information on the data.

Question: **How can I get box plots to be close to each other for a given x axis value (as is done in hue) without refactorizing x to the hue value and the x axis value?**

For example, here I want to overlay the points to the box plot and want the points further colored by `‘sex’`. Example:

```
plt.figure(figsize = (5, 5))

sns.boxplot(x = 'class', y = 'age', 
            hue = 'embarked', dodge = True, data = df)


sns.swarmplot(x = 'class', y = 'age', 
              dodge = True,
              color = '0.25',
              
              hue = 'sex', data = df)

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor = (1.5, 1))
```

EDIT:
The idea would be to have something that looks like the 'S' box for 'Third' in the plot (I made a fake example in powerpoint, so `hue` in both `boxplot` and `swarmplot` are the same to overlay the points on the appropriate boxes).

[image]

**Is there a way to make this plot without first refactorizing the x-axis to ‘first-S’, ‘first-C’, ‘first-Q’, ‘second-S’, etc and then add `hue` by `’sex’` in both plots?**

Answer (score 1):

## Using original `x` as `col` and `hue` as `x`

To work with two types of `hue`, seaborn's alternative is to create a `FacetGrid`.  The original `x=` then becomes the `col=` (or the `row=`), and one of the hues becomes the new `x=`.

Here is an example. Note that `aspect=` controls the width of the individual subplots (the width being `height*aspect`).

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
g = sns.catplot(kind='box', x='embarked', y='age', hue='sex', col='class',
                dodge=True, palette='spring',
                height=5, aspect=0.5, data=df)
g.map_dataframe(sns.swarmplot, x='embarked', y='age', hue='sex', palette=['0.25'] * 2, size=2, dodge=True)
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    # use title as x-label
    ax.set_xlabel(ax.get_title())
    ax.set_title('')
    # remove y-axis except for the left-most columns
    if len(ax.get_ylabel()) == 0:
        ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
        ax.tick_params(axis='y', left=False)
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)
plt.show()
```

[image: combining sns.boxplot and sns.swarmplot with two hue variables]

## Only using `hue` for the `swarmplot`, without dodge

Here is a variant, where the `boxplot` doesn't use `hue`, but the `swarmplot` does.  A bit more padding can be added inside the subplots, and the boxplots can be made touching via `width=1`. Suppressing the outliers of the `boxplot` looks cleaner, as they would overlap with the outlier of the `swarmplot`.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
df['embarked'] = pd.Categorical(df['embarked'], ['S', 'C', 'Q'])  # force a strict order
g = sns.catplot(kind='box', x='embarked', y='age', col='class',
                dodge=True, palette='summer', width=1, showfliers=False,
                height=5, aspect=0.5, data=df)
g.map_dataframe(sns.swarmplot, x='embarked', y='age', hue='sex', palette=['b', 'r'], size=2, dodge=False)
g.add_legend()
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    # use title as x-label
    ax.set_xlabel(ax.get_title())
    ax.set_title('')
    # remove y-axis except for the left-most columns
    if len(ax.get_ylabel()) == 0:
        ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
        ax.tick_params(axis='y', left=False)
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
ax.set_xlim(xmin - 0.2, xmax + 0.2)  # add a bit more spacing between the groups
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)
plt.show()
```

[image: catplot using hue for swarmplot]

Comment: my issue is that one of my groups (eg the x-axis in scatter grid) doesn't have as much data as the other group, and I wanted the two to overlap rather than plot side-by-side? is there a somewhat pythonic way to accomplish this or am I stuck with facit grid?

Comment: You can change the spacing to zero (`plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)`), to make the facet grid look like a single subplot. The `aspect=` of `sns.catplot` can be reduced to use less width (but this doesn't work well for this example, as the swarms needs some width).  You might want to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75149732/edit) your post and add a sketch of how you'd want the plot to look like.

Comment: I added a variant which only uses hue for the swarmplot